# On Windows paperclip uses "file" command in Ruby Devkit, but gives error "Errno::EEXIST in ArticlesController#create"

Tags: windows, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

On Ubuntu paperclip file upload works with builtin file command. On Windows I did both install Ruby Devkit or file.exe in PATH variable: None of this helps! I get:

```
File exists @ sys_fail2 - C:/Users/Lap127/AppData/Local/Temp/3e26e8e7aa5f147d0c6c7ae71efc007220170215-7312-1bv14wq.txt
Extracted source (around line #24):

def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params) #line 24 here

  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
```

How do I upload attachments with paperclip on windows without getting error, that the **new** file already exists?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue with this before, and it took a bit of searching, but here's where the problem was for tempfiles and Ruby on Windows.

`C:\<path_to_ruby_file>\lib\ruby\<version>\tempfile.rb`

Based on this post: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/187311

Our team was able to find the problem.

While they have a solution, we ended up writing our own.
You want (~Line 204):

```
def unlink
  #----ADDED THIS LINE---#
  return if @unlinked
  #-----END ADDED LINE----#
  begin
    File.unlink(@tmpfile.path)
  rescue Errno::ENOENT
  rescue Errno::EACCES
    # may not be able to unlink on Windows; just ignore
    return
  end
  ObjectSpace.undefine_finalizer(self)
  @unlinked = true
end
alias delete unlink
```

If you are still getting this error, let me know! Additionally, if you could check that the content of the tempfile is what you expect, that might be useful.